# MongoDB distinct then filter

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Suppose I have a book collection:

```
{"name": "Mongodb", "authors": [{"name": "John"}, {"name": "Peter"}, {"name": "Joe"}]}  
{"name": "MySQL", "authors": [{"name": "John"}, {"name": "Alice"}, {"name": "Kate"}]}
{"name": "SQL Server", "authors": [{"name": "John"}, {"name": "Steve"}]}
```

I want to find the authors who have co-authored with `John`.

When I use the query: `db.book.distinct('authors.name', {'authors.name': 'John'})`

It will return the following result: `[John, Peter, Joe, Alice, Kate, Steve]`

However, I don't want `John` to be in the list.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

There you go:

```
db.book.aggregate({
    $match: {
        "authors.name": "John" // only look at documents that contain "John" in the list of authors (this part could use an index on "authors.name")
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$authors" // flatten the authors array into separate documents
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: null, // throw all documents in the same bucket
        authors: { $addToSet: "$authors.name" } // add all authors' names into an array called "authors" eliminating duplicate entries
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        "co-authors": {
            $filter: { // remove "John" from the list of entries
                "input": "$authors",
                "as": "this",
                "cond": { $ne: [ "$$this", "John" ] }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

However, I think your current "solution" is way more elegant. All it's missing is a tiny little bit of client-side filtering (removing the "John" entry from the list of returned entries).

Comment: Nice.   Beat me to it,   :-D

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti: I'm sorry about that. ;)